# CAKEPHP 3.1 clear form after submit

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

Usually on cakephp2 i used to unset form data and everything was ok.

Some times i use redirects to clear it. But i cant do that in this current page.

Anyone has found this issue or a solution for this?

Comment: Turn Off Autocomplete for Input, If you stay on same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are staying on the "add" page after successfully adding a record, for example to allow entry of multiple records more quickly, you'll need to reset the entity after saving. For example, if you're entering Posts, your controller will look something like:

```
$post = $this->Posts->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
        $post = $this->Posts->newEntity(); // <- Reset the entity
    }
}
$this->set(compact('post'));
```

(Error checking, flash messages, etc. all left out for brevity.)

Comment: You'll probably also have to clear the request data, as the form helpers entity context will look there too (first request data, then entity data). https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.6/src/View/Form/EntityContext.php#L208-L211

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to simply redirect to the same page.
I had the problem that not everything was deleted

```
$contact = new ContactForm();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Submited.'));
            $this->request->data(null);
            $contact = new ContactForm();
            return $this->redirect('/(Same Page)');// This did the final trick for me
        } 
    }
```